# How to use query modal on different pages? This only works in one page

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I use this modal on different pages? I tried everything I can but it just works in one page.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Delete</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Delete</a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('#confirm-delete1').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
    });
</script>
```

Anchor / link:

```
<a href="#" data-href="delete-journal.php?id='.$id.'" data-toggle="#confirm-delete1"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o" alt="Delete journal" title="Delete journal"></i>delete</a>
```

Comment: First, for this code to work as is you need to echo the `$id`. If you want the user to pass a phrase/word to authenticate why not use a form with a text input? Then the PHP will validate the phrase/word. With authentication via javascript the key/phrase will be exposed.

Comment: It's going to be a longer process that way. As far as I know (I don't code JS a lot) the confirm box isn't customizable for text. Since the code is on the client side a user can view it and find the pass phrase. I'd authenticate server side via a form. You could also do it all via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

> I'd echo out my the $id and the whole php block, i just did not include it here. I just want to know on how to have a prompt confirmation box, if i clicked the delete link, it will prompt a message "Do you want to delete this?" with a TEXTBOX where the CONFIRMATION CODE will be entered. If confirmation code = $confirmation_code then it will delete the record, otherwise it will not.

That would take quite a few steps in order to get the desired effect.  But I can give you a list of steps you'd need to take:

1. You can make a prompt with the `prompt()` function, you can also put a message with the prompt as the first parameter, you can *also* store the return of that prompt in a variable to use later. (e.g. `var code = prompt("Enter a confirmation code")`...)
2. Perform a Ajax request to sent that data to the server.
3. Compare the data server-side and perform any actions you need to server-side, or send data back to the client if you need to do any operations client-side as well.